# I keep getting "end if without block if" error

Tags: vba, if-statement

My data set is all in column A and i am trying to read between rows 2 and 300. I need to read each cell to see if it has information in it. If it does not have any information then it will go to the next cell below. When it does find information in a cell it needs to create a new work book and use that cell value as the title as the workbook name and loop till row 300. The work book needs to be saved on my dekstop in folder called test. I keep getting "end if without block if" error

```
Sub blair() 
      Dim strName As String
      strName = ActiveCell.Value

      For ptr = 2 To 300
          If Cells(ptr, "a") = vbNullString Then
              Cells(ptr, "a") = Cells(ptr, "a").Offset(-1, 0)
          Else
              Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
              With NewBook
                  .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\test\" & strName & ".xls"
                  .Close
          End If
      Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation of your code which helps to see where it is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The error happens because you have not ended the `With` segment with the proper `End With` statement. VBA interprets the `End` as ending the `With` segment and then proceeds to have 2 `Ifs` open with none closed.